# How to change the DirectionLayout property of SSRS Report`s tablix dynamically to make the report supports english and arabic languages

Tags: reporting-services

I`m working in a program that supports English and Arabic languages and in current days we are developing the program reports.

We choosed to use SSRS with ReportViewer control in WindowsFormsApplication(C#) 
I searched for a way to change the DirectionLayout property of the tablix according to language(LTR english, RTL arabic) and I tried a lot of solutions but with no success.

I do not want to create two reports or create one report with two tablixes one for each language.

Now I`m trying to do the following:

1. Use SSRS web services to get report definition
2. Edit the report definition (convert Tablex DirectionLayout to RTL)
3. Use SSRS Execution Service to load the definition and render the report
4. assign the renderd report to ReportViewr control

I would like to know is that possible? And where can I search to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

1) Depending on the version of SSRS you are using, you can use GetReportDefinition method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.getreportdefinition(v=sql.100).aspx) or GetItemDefinition (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.getitemdefinition.aspx)

2) You can use the RDL Object Model to edit the RDL, although it's not trivial and the classes of the Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel namespace are marked internal (SSRS 2008 R2 and higher). You can find sample code by Teo Lachev at http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2010/03/08/where-is-rdlom-in-r2.aspx and by Lionel Ringenbach at https://github.com/Ucodia/Blog-CustomReportingServices.

For reference information about the classes and methods of the RDL Object Model, start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff493708.

3-4) I think it would be easier to deploy your edited report back to the server and then call it with the ReportViewer control. Then you can just leverage available methods in a straightforward manner. The ReportViewer control can handle the rendering directly. Here's information on deployment via the Web service: http://tomyrhymond.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/sql-server-reporting-services-deploying-rdl-files/